# ItemWriter rollback but data is committed to the database

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I am using a Existing DAO autowired in my ItemWriter to insert elements in the database.

I have set the commit-interval = 5.

In my xml (read), i have put invalid data in the 5th element to test out the restart feature.

here is my ItemWriter:

```
@Component("transactionItemWriter")
public class TransactionInteracItemWriter implements   ItemStreamWriter<TransactionConciliationInterac> {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TransactionInteracItemWriter.class);
    @Autowired
    private ConciliationContext conciliationContext;
    @Autowired
    private ServiceTransactionConciliationInterac paiementService;
    private int transactionCount;

    /**
     * @see ItemWriter#write(java.util.List)
     */
    public void write(List<? extends TransactionConciliationInterac> data) throws Exception {

    int index = ++transactionCount - 1;


    while (index < data.size()) {
        TransactionConciliationInterac trx = data.get(index);
        paiementService.insertAndReturnKey(trx,conciliationContext.getIdSommaire().toString());
    index = ++transactionCount - 1;
    }
}
```

the paiementService is a Spring bean using JDBCTemplate to insert data in the DB.

my config :

```
        <batch:step id="traitementXmlIemtTransactionStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" start-limit="10">
            <batch:chunk reader="IemtXmlTransactionReader" processor="IemtXmlTransactionConvertProcessor" writer="transactionItemWriter" commit-interval="5"/>
            <batch:transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="transactionStepListener" />
            </batch:listeners>

        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

Now, when i run this, i see that i get an exception (DataIntegrityEx) :

```
<Rollback for RuntimeException: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Data truncation: Data too long for column  'TRANSACTIONTYPE' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data  truncation: Data too long for column 'TRANSACTIONTYPE' at row 1>
2012-12-11 09:50:28,949 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate]  - <Handling exception: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException, caused by:  org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [];  Data truncation: Data too long for column 'TRANSACTIONTYPE' at row 1; nested exception is  com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'TRANSACTIONTYPE' at row 1>
2012-12-11 09:50:28,949 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Handling fatal exception explicitly (rethrowing first of 1): org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'TRANSACTIONTYPE' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'TRANSACTIONTYPE' at row 1>
2012-12-11 09:50:28,950 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] -    <Encountered an error executing the step>
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'TRANSACTIONTYPE' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'TRANSACTIONTYPE' at row 1
at     org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:101)
```

The step status look like this :

```
<Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=3, version=2, name=traitementXmlIemtTransactionStep, status=FAILED, exitStatus=FAILED, readCount=5, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=1>
```

This look ok, i can see i have read 5 elements, 0 were written and 1 rollback occurred.

BUT when i look in the Database, i can see that the first 4 elements were committed!!!!

I need help to find what i am doing wrong!

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found my issue!!!  I was using MySql and by default, it uses MyIsam engine which does not support transactions.

Changed it to innoDB and now everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `ServiceTransactionConciliationInterac` has it's own transaction handling, e.g. that every call to `paiementService.insertAndReturnKey()` is surrounded by a Transaction. Spring Batch would not be able to roll back those inner transactions.

Comment: I checked for this since i tough it would be the case, but there is no @transactional or transaction management xml in these services.

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to innoDB and now everything works great.

`spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`